# Create top lists using Spotify Web Api

Tags: spotify

Anyone have a good ide how I can create music top lists using Spotify or echonest Web API?

For example create a top 25 list of music from the 80's of the genre rock in Sweden. Or the most streamed tracks on the global market of genre pop for the year 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Search endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/), you can retrieve tracks by genre within some year interval. It also accepts a market parameter, but the order is not guaranteed to be by popularity though.

https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=genre:pop+year:1980-2020&market=SE

This is probably as close as you can get using the Web API as it is today.

There are playlists that are updated with the most popular tracks in most (if not all) markets, although not by genre. For Sweden's Top 50, see http://open.spotify.com/user/spotify/playlist/7jmQBEvJyGHPqKEl5UcEe9.

Comment: Hi Michaelt, I have looked at what you are suggestion. What is the 'popularity' parameter in the response. Can I search as you suggested and then sort based on 'popularity'?

Comment: No, there's no way to sort by popularity unfortunately. The popularity signifies how many times the track has been played recently.